# How can i chdir() without writing all path

Tags: php, public-html

I've ran into issue where I need to use `chdir` function and it seems that I need to use full path for it to fully function.

Is there any way of not doing this? I would like to use simplier path like `~/` but it does not work.

```
        $dir = "files";
        chdir($dir); // "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure" 
        array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', ($filesArray = glob("*.*"))), SORT_DESC, $filesArray); //Tipo sortina kazkaip magiskai
        $dir = "/home/galgalda/domains/tortonas.tk/public_html"; //How do i change this line?
        chdir($dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

```
$dir = "files";
chdir($dir); // "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure" 
array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', ($filesArray = glob("*.*"))), SORT_DESC, 
$filesArray); //Tipo sortina kazkaip magiskai
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; //How do i change this line?
chdir($dir);
```